# Who is Taller/Tallest/The Tallest?

Tags: american-english

Who is ____________ , Sara or Janet?

This is a confusing question because I'm not sure which is correct:

- tallest
- taller
- the tallest

Seem to all work fine. Which one is considered "best"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**"Taller"** is the correct answer for this, because you are comparing only **two** nouns, and in this case, Sara and Janet.

"Taller" is a *comparative* adjective, those which are used to compare one noun to another noun.

The other choices you gave, "tallest" and "the tallest" are both in *superlative* form, meaning they are used to compare three or more nouns.

For more information, you can try visiting http://www.eflnet.com/tutorials/adjcompsup.php

Comment: But one could also say 'Who is the taller, Sarah or Janet?'.

Comment: When comparing only two nouns in only once sentence, you do not need to use "the", unless you're stating it differently, like "Sara is the taller one between the two of them."

Comment: I agree. But one does hear it. Also in *Who is the taller of the two girls*.